# How do you know the index of an element that in the sub list

Tags: python, list

How do you know the index of an element that is in a sub list? [A similar question was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python) for lists without nesting

Like so:

```
L=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

What I want to be as output when the element is `3`:

```
output=[0][2]
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: The same way you do it in that link

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by `output = [0][2]` since this is bound to throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def get_sublist_index(lists, item):
    for sublist in lists:
        if item in sublist:
            return lists.index(sublist), sublist.index(item)

>>> L=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> get_sublist_index(L, 3)
(0, 2)
```

Or to get every item:

```
def get_sublist_index(lists, item):
    for sublist in lists:
        if item in sublist:
            yield lists.index(sublist), sublist.index(item)
```

Making a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
>>> L=[[1,2,3],[4,3,6]]
>>> get_sublist_index(L, 3)
<generator object get_sublist_index at 0x1056c5e08>
>>> [i for i in get_sublist_index(L, 3)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1)]
```

Or if you don't want a generator:

```
def get_sublist_index(lists, item):
    outList = []
    for sublist in lists:
        if item in sublist:
            outList.append((lists.index(sublist), sublist.index(item)))
    return outList

>>> get_sublist_index(L, 3)
[(0, 2), (1, 1)]
>>>
```

Comment: This only returns the first item you find unless that's what OP wants.

Comment: @MooingRawr  Thanks. I'll change it.

Answer (score 3):

```
L=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,3]]

a = 3

print([(i,j) for i,x in enumerate(L) if a in x for j,b in enumerate(x) if b == a])
#[(0, 2), (2, 1), (2, 4)]
```

using list comprehension you can dig and return all the sub values. If you need to go deeper just keep chaining the list comprehension or write a function to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
def find_sublist(outer, what):
    for i, lst in enumerate(outer):
        try:
            return i, lst.index(what)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Actually, `output = [0][2]` will throw an exception. Not sure what you mean by this. Do you want a tuple of two elements? I will assume you do.

You could alternatively use something more elegant, like

```
In [8]: [(i, sublist.index(3)) for i, sublist in enumerate(L) if 3 in sublist]
Out[8]: [(0, 2)]

In [9]: [(i, sublist.index(4)) for i, sublist in enumerate(L) if 4 in sublist]
Out[9]: [(1, 0)]
```

Comment: `find_sublist(L, 3)` only gives me an output of 0 and the OP says the output should be `0, 2`

Answer (score 2):

*"One-line"* solution using [**numpy.where**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [**numpy.transpose**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) methods(the initial input array was extended to cover a complex case):

```
import numpy as np

L = [[1,2,3],[4,3,6]]  # 3 occurs twice
output = np.transpose(np.where(np.array(L) == 3))

print(output)
```

The output:

```
 [[0 2]
  [1 1]]
```

Comment: if the list has multiple of the same in it (for example `L = [[1,2,3],[4,3,6]]`, it returns: `array([[0, 1], [2, 1]])`

Comment: meaning that it returns `[place1x, place2x], [place1y, place2y]` when they want it to return `[place1x, place1y], [place2x, place2y]`

Comment: @rassar, right, I've fixed that, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

You should always count on `enumerate` for tasks that require indices and sequences:

```
def find_index(l, val=3):
    # res holds results
    res = []
    # Go through every sublist in l 
    # index1 indicates which sublist we check
    for index1, sublist in enumerate(l):
        # Go through every item in sublist 
        # index2 indicates which item we check
        for index2, item in enumerate(sublist):
            # append to result if we find a match
            if item == val:
                res.append([index1, index2])
    return res
```

With a sample list:

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 4, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```

this returns:

```
find_index(L)
[[0, 2], [1, 4], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider returning a dict of indices using [`more_itertools.locate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.locate).

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit


def indices(iterable, item):
    """Return a dict of indices of all located items."""
    d = {}
    for i, sub in enumerate(iterable):
        val = list(mit.locate(sub, lambda x: x == item))
        if not val:
            continue
        d[i] = val

    return d
```

**Demo**

Given shallow, nested iterables:

```
indices([[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]], 3)
# {0: [2]}

indices([[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 3]], 3)
# {0: [2], 2: [1, 2]}
```

Here multiple appearances are recorded.