# Python: How to find the value of a number in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23],[24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31],[32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,],[40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47],[48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55],[56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63]])
```

How can I write a function that takes a number 0-63 as input, and tells me where that number is in the array?

example: function(0) returns a[0,0]; function(13) returns a[5,1]

Comment: Of course, this is possible.

Comment: @ForceBru I changed the wording. I assumed it's possible, I just have no idea how to do it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949132/how-do-you-know-the-index-of-an-element-that-in-the-sub-list/40949199#40949199

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest way (gives you the indices in oposite order) is

```
np.argwhere(a==13)
```

gives:

```
array([[1, 5]])
```